# Integrate AIML files in android studio

Tags: java, android, bots, aiml

I'm trying to make a chatbot using android studio but i can't find a way to connect it to the AIML files correctly here is the code i tried

```
String request = s;
            String response = chatSession.multisentenceRespond(request);
            while (response.contains("&lt;")) response = response.replace("&lt;","<");
            while (response.contains("&gt;")) response = response.replace("&gt;",">");
            if(response.equals("Too much recursion in AIML"))
                return  "";
            else
                return response;
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What are you trying to do exactly?  The above code looks like its just trying to replace escaped < and > characters with the raw values-  and in a very inefficient way.

Comment: i'm trying to create a chat bot using alice knowledge base i can't integrate the AIML files to get results for the written text

Comment: "integrate the aiml files"-  you need to explain what you mean by this.  What are you specifically trying to do with those files?  Just saying "integrate" doesn't tell us what you're trying to do or how you're trying to do it, it just tells us you want to use those files somehow.

Comment: I want to get a sentence or a question from the user interface like "who is Newton?" the code takes the question and search in the AIML files for the answer and returns it to the program which displays it on the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think by 'integrate' you mean that you want the bot to scan the `AIML` file and give a response according to the input provided by you.

For this, you have to follow following steps:

1. First put your AIML files in `assets` folder in Android Studio file hierarchy.
2. Then you have to save those files to your phone memory.
3. Then you have to use an interpreter like `Program AB` to get appropriate response according to the data you enter.

You can refer [this link](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-baking-a-simple-chatbot-in-30-minutes-aiml-ff43c3269025) to get you started with it.

Comment: I need to know whether I need internet connection if i use aiml and also if there a way to design an offline chatbot either on the client (android) or at the server (php apache)? pls help

Comment: You don't need internet to use AIML at all. Chatbot can be made offline as well on android devices. Just follow the link in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I downloaded the exemplary app created there and installed it. I ran it but it keeps on saying i have no answer for that for every line i type even for hi. If you have better knowledge of the procedure in that link could you help me?

Comment: That demo copies the AIML files to your SD card. Make sure you have given the application access permission to your external memory in manifest file. That error can occur if you don't give external memory access or if the files are not getting copied properly.